# how to click cancel in prompt box?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension to suppress a prompt box.
The access is protected in server side and user is triggered with prompt box for username/password as shown below,

[image: prompt box]

I am injecting a content_script in the url at document_start and trying to detect the presence of this prompt, if present "cancel" button need to be clicked. 
Here is a test link to get the login prompt,
http://128.199.223.179/testing/test.php

Comment: I don't know chrome extensions, but emulating a click on the cancel button is probably not the way to go, because not everyone has the same size screen, thus the button would be in different positions. Instead, try to see if you can detect if a un and pwd are required when a page is requested and then display your own GUI to collect that data and try requesting the page again with the un and pwd.

Comment: Inspect the page DOM first in devtools. It's possible the dialog is shown by the browser itself in which case it can't be clicked programmatically.

Comment: The prompt is from Chrome  browser itself.

Comment: Do you know the function name of the prompt?

Comment: very suspicious for an off-topic question ro have 4 points. are coworkers bumping it? read s.o. guidelines to be ontopic (show research, attempts and code issues).

Comment: @zig mandel : its my personal project

Comment: Can you post a valid url that brings up an authentication prompt so that I can test my  solution?

Comment: @EyuelDK : here is test link, http://128.199.223.179/testing/test.php . need to click cancel on this prompt in chrome browser

Comment: What is your end goal? Is it to just close the prompt? Is it to autofill the prompt? Be sure to share your end goal clearly as it does seriously affect the extent I can help you with.

Comment: @EyuelDK  I need to click cancel on the prompt if present.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish it just using the js chrome api. You either would need to make a NPAPI plugin and actually change the behavior of the browser or use an external program to click the button via global xy coordinates. I think preventing the prompt might be easier than actually clicking cancel, but I'm just hypothesizing.

Comment: @EyuelDK is it possible to prevent the prompt in js ? if yes, pls let me know the steps

Comment: Kinda, but what do you intend on doing once you "close" the prompt? There is no page to show because the server hasn't sent you any html data. Are you attempting to auto-login or redirect to some other page. Or do you just want to show an empty white page.
Note that, the prompt isn't opened by the page but rather by the browser itself. It happens when authentication is required to retrieve server response. The fact that the prompt appears means that the server has not given you data to display. Thus, what would you do after you prevent the prompt.

Comment: @EyuelDK  : excellent question :) when we stop the prompt   the server will respond with 401, and it is handled at the client end. We just need to stop the prompt from showing as there is fallback. Pls let me know how to close this prompt when shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You technically can't close the prompt only using the javascript api... You might need to use an NPAPI plugin or other external software such as Selenium to emulate a click on the close button.

But, what you can do is prevent that dialog from popping up in the first place by intercepting an authentication request.

First add "webRequest" permission in your manifest. Then try this code:

```
// to listen to all urls use { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details) {
  return {cancel: true};
}, {urls: ["http://128.199.223.179/testing/test.php"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

For better documentation, visit https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired

Comment: It worked, had to add persistent:true in manifest. thank you :)